# Injecting custom repository using inversify

Tags: node.js, express, inversifyjs, mikro-orm

I'm practicing mikroorm with inversify.

I have `TodoEntity`

```
import { Entity, Property, PrimaryKey, EntityRepositoryType } from '@mikro-orm/core'
import { TodoRepository } from '../../repositories'


@Entity({tableName: 'todo'})
export class TodoEntity {

  // [EntityRepositoryType]?: TodoRepository;

  @PrimaryKey()
  id?: number

  @Property()
  title: string

  @Property()
  description: string

  constructor(title: string, description: string) {
    this.title = title
    this.description = description
  }
}
```

And this is the custom repository `TodoRepository`

```
import { EntityRepository } from '@mikro-orm/mysql'
import { Repository } from '@mikro-orm/core'
import { TodoEntity } from '../models/entities'
import { injectable } from "inversify"


@injectable()
@Repository(TodoEntity)
export class TodoRepository extends EntityRepository<TodoEntity> {}
```

I'm injecting the `repository` into the `service` via

```
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify"
import { TodoRepository } from "../repositories"
import TYPES from "../../di/types"
import autoBind from "auto-bind";

@injectable()
export class TodoService {

  private todoRepository: TodoRepository

  constructor (@inject(TYPES.TodoRepository) todoRepository: TodoRepository) {
    this.todoRepository = todoRepository
    autoBind(this)
  }

  public async getTodos() {
    return await this.todoRepository.findAll()
  }
}
```

and this is my controller

```
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify"
import { TodoService } from "../services/todoService"
import { Request, Response, NextFunction} from "express";
import TYPES from "../../di/types";
import autoBind from "auto-bind";

@injectable()
export class TodoController {

  todoService: TodoService

  constructor(@inject(TYPES.TodoService) todoService: TodoService) {
    this.todoService = todoService
    autoBind(this)
  }

  public async getAllTodos(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    res.send(await this.todoService.getTodos())
  }
}
```

This is the types

```
const TYPES = {
  TodoRepository: Symbol.for("TodoRepository"),
  TodoService: Symbol.for("TodoService"),
  TodoController: Symbol.for("TodoController")
};

export default TYPES
```

Container

```
import { TodoRepository } from "../todos/repositories"
import { TodoService } from "../todos/services/todoService"
import { TodoController } from "../todos/controllers/todoController"
import { Container } from "inversify"
import TYPES from "./types"



const container = new Container();

container.bind<TodoController>(TYPES.TodoController).to(TodoController);
container.bind<TodoService>(TYPES.TodoService).to(TodoService);
container.bind<TodoRepository>(TYPES.TodoRepository).to(TodoRepository);


export { container }
```

How can I inject the custom repository to service, i'm having an error saying
`Error: Missing required @injectable annotation in: SqlEntityRepository`

But when I  did not include the `repository` only the `service` and the `controller` and I tried to test dump. the DI is just working fined

Im following this example [Inversify example with mikro orm](https://github.com/PodaruDragos/inversify-example-app)

but on the example he's not using the custom repo, any idea where can I start to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add decorator with decorate utility that inversify is providing.

```
import { decorate, injectable } from "inversify";
import SomeClass from "some-module";

decorate(injectable(), SomeClass);
return SomeClass;
```

Read docs over here: https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/inheritance.md#what-can-i-do-when-my-base-class-is-provided-by-a-third-party-module

Also there is global Container option `skipBaseClassChecks` that will skip `@injectable` check on all base classes.